# ".TextToColumns" with ".NumberFormat"

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I've got a text file I'm trying to save as an XLSX file. However before saving and closing I need to perform a TextToColumns and ALSO I need column "H" to remain in "Text" format.

The below code converts column "H" to "Text" format but then when the ".TextToColumns" executes column "H" changes to a "Custom" format thus changing the the data.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook dataB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet dataS;

        string path = @"C:\Users\fakename\Desktop\EXTRACTED_FORMATTED sampleFile.csv";

        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        dataB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0,
            false, 5, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            false, false, Missing.Value, false, false, false);
        dataB.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
        oXL.Visible = true;
        dataS = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)dataB.ActiveSheet;

        Range excelRange = dataS.get_Range("H1").EntireColumn;
        excelRange.NumberFormat = "@";

        dataS.get_Range("A1", ("A" + dataS.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).TextToColumns(
            Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, false,
            false, false, false, false, true, "|", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        dataS.Name = "PSH";
        dataS.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\fakename\Desktop\2\moresamplefiles", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault);
        dataB.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        oXL.Quit();
```

Comment: off the point, but would your code not be tidier with a using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel statement?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to transcribe this into your c# code but you need to set the [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) within the parameters of the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx). I suspect it has to do with one or more of your `Type.Missing` values. You need to pass in an array of arrays. The nested arrays decribe the position and format; e.g. Array(4, 2) is the fourth field in `xlTextFormat` format.